# Handle rendering array of editable components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `contentEditable` component:

**EditableComponent.js**

```
const EditableComponent = (props) => {
    return <p contentEditable>{props.children}</p>;
};
```

In the `ParentComponent` I can add `EditableComponent`s to an `array (someArr)` with `useState`, and then I pass `someArr` and `setSomeArray` via `props` to another component (`AllEditable`) to render it:

**ParentComponent.js**

```
import EditableComponent from "./components";
import AllEditable from "./components";

const ParentComponent = () => {
   
    const [someArr, setSomeArr] = useState([]);

    const handleNewEditable = () => {
        setContentArr((prevContentArr) => {
            return [...prevContentArr, <EditableComponent />];
        });
    };

    return (
         <div className="wrapper">
             <AllEditable someArr={someArr} setSomeArr={setSomeArr} />
             <div>
                 <button onClick={handleNewEditable}>Add</button>
             </div>
         </div>
    );
};
```

Each rendered component (`EditableComponent`) have a `span` with the content 'X' that should delete the target `onClick`:

**AllEditable.js**

```
const AllEditable= (props) => {
    const deleteContentHandler = (index) => {
        props.setSomeArr((prevState) => {
            return prevState.filter((_, idx) => idx !== index);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {props.someArr.map((content, idx) => {
                return (
                    <div key={`content-${idx}`}>
                        <span onClick={() => {deleteContentHandler(idx);}}>
                            X
                        </span>
                        <div>{content}</div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

### The problem:

It doesn't matter which component I'm trying to delete, it removes the **last** component (even in the `Components` section in the developer tools) and I'm pretty sure that the logic behind deleting (`filter`) works well.

I tried deleting the `contentEditable` attribute, and added some unique random text in each component and then it **worked as expected!**.

### Things I tried

- Creating a new `array` without the removed target
- Nesting the components in `someArr` in objects with `key: index`, example: `{idx: 0, content: <EditableComponent />}`
- Added a `function - onDoubleClick` for each `EditableComponent` to toggle the attribute `contentEditable`, true or false.
- Replaced the element in `EditableComponent` to `<textarea></textarea>` instead of `<p contentEditable></p>`

Comment: Is `setContentArr` supposed to be `setSomeArr`?

Comment: Right, it's from the original code, forgot to update it in the minimal code example.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is all your `EditableComponent` components have the same key (because you haven't declared `key` on them). React cannot identify which `EditableComponent` you want to delete. You can check [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

I'd suggest you add a key attribute like below

```
<EditableComponent key={prevContentArr.length - 1}/>
```

For safer index reservation, you should use `map` instead `filter`

```
const AllEditable= (props) => {
    const deleteContentHandler = (index) => {
        props.setSomeArr((prevState) => {
            return prevState.map((x, idx) => idx !== index ? x : null);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {props.someArr.map((content, idx) => {
                return content ? (
                  <div key={`content-${idx}`}>
                      <span onClick={() => {deleteContentHandler(idx);}}>
                          X
                      </span>
                      <div>{content}</div>
                  </div>
              ) : null;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

```js
const { useState } = React

const EditableComponent = (props) => {
    return <p contentEditable>{props.children}</p>;
};

const AllEditable= (props) => {
const deleteContentHandler = (index) => {
    props.setSomeArr((prevState) => {
        return prevState.map((x, idx) => idx !== index ? x : null);
    });
};

return (
    <div>
        {props.someArr.map((content, idx) => {
            return content ? (
              <div key={`content-${idx}`}>
                  <span onClick={() => {deleteContentHandler(idx);}}>
                      X
                  </span>
                  <div>{content}</div>
              </div>
          ) : null;
        })}
    </div>
);
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
   
    const [someArr, setSomeArr] = useState([]);

    const handleNewEditable = () => {
        setSomeArr((prevContentArr) => {
            return [...prevContentArr, <EditableComponent key={prevContentArr.length - 1}/>];
        });
    };

    return (
         <div className="wrapper">
             <AllEditable someArr={someArr} setSomeArr={setSomeArr} />
             <div>
                 <button onClick={handleNewEditable}>Add</button>
             </div>
         </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

*Side note that keys with index values are not the best because your array keeps changing that would make key changes as well. You can use some unique key generator to handle that situation instead.*

Comment: It's not working as expected! and if that is the problem then why it didn't work when I tried working with objects when I compared the `idx` value and yet it works with non-editable content?

Comment: Actually, index usage is the rootcause of your problem, so I changed the approach a bit on your `filter` as well. you can check my updated answer @001

Answer (score 0):

You shluld change the way you set keys, setting the element key to: "content-index" is confusing for react, because once you remove an item all the indexes will change, and therefore your keys.

So you need to find a way to have static keys for your elements. That way everytime they render, the key will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is working correctly and in fact it is deleting the correct elements, however since you are using the index to identify elements, you will never see this since it will always appear that only the last one is removed (when the array updates, the indices will update too).

So if you had 0,1,2 and removed 1 now you have an array with indices 0,1

To test this you can place a reference to the index when rendering the content editable div, based on testing you can see that the correct element is in fact being removed:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const EditableComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <p contentEditable>
      {props.children}
      {props.idtfy}
    </p>
  );
};

const AllEditable = (props) => {
  const deleteContentHandler = (index) => {
    props.setSomeArr((prevState) => {
      return prevState.filter((_, idx) => idx !== index);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.someArr.map((content, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={`content-${idx}`}>
            <span>{idx}</span>
            <span
              onClick={() => {
                deleteContentHandler(idx);
              }}
            >
              X
            </span>
            <div>{content}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [someArr, setSomeArr] = useState([]);

  const handleNewEditable = () => {
    setSomeArr((prevContentArr) => {
      return [
        ...prevContentArr,
        <EditableComponent idtfy={prevContentArr.length + 1} />
      ];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <AllEditable someArr={someArr} setSomeArr={setSomeArr} />
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleNewEditable}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

That said, your `key` should probably point to some static value, but that will only impact rendering order, not which item is being clicked/closed.